Building a pkpass for Apple Wallet
I am trying to build a simple wallet pass in order to test the feature. What I do:

Create a Pass Type ID Identifier
Create a certificate by uploading a certificate signing request
Convert the certificate to .pem
Import the certificate as .cer in Keychain. It is not trusted for some reason so I manually mark at as trusted. I see that the organizational unit is G4 so...
I download the Worldwide Developer Relations - G4 file from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/
For root certificate I download Apple Inc. Root
I make both Apple's certificate to be .pem
I create a FullChain like so

cat PassCertificate.pem AppleWWDRG4.pem AppleRootCA.pem > FullChain.pem


I successfully verify the FullChain.pem like this

openssl verify -CAfile AppleRootCA.pem -untrusted AppleWWDRG4.pem PassCertificate.pem


I create a signature with my pass files in MyPass folder like this

openssl smime -binary -sign \
  -certfile AppleWWDRG4.pem \
  -signer PassCertificate.pem \
  -inkey pass.key \
  -in MyPass/manifest.json \
  -out MyPass/signature \
  -outform DER


The signature is created. The problem is verifying the signature. I've tried many ways to verify it, but it always fails. One if the ways is:

openssl cms -verify \
  -inform DER \
  -in MyPass/signature \
  -content MyPass/manifest.json \
  -CAfile FullChain.pem


Assuming it doesn't fail, I continue to zip and make the files in MyPass folder as .pkpass, which doesn't work as a pass on the iPhone of course.

My MyPass folder has:
icon and icon@2x, thumbnail and thumbnail@2x (all png) manifest.json and pass.json (which has correct teamID and pass identifier). The manifest contains only the pics and the pass.json.
What am I doing wrong?
It could be related to the Pass Certificate that I donwload from Apple Developer portal not being trusted and me marking it as trusted, but why is it not trusted in the first place? It is a certificate created by Apple.
